# Pandas: filtering a dictionary composed by several data frames gives a variable error, why?

Tags: pandas, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary with 365 data frames, one for each day. Here, to be simple lets just assume 3 data frames.

```
dataframes = {'Df_20100101': DataFrame, 'Df_20100102': DataFrame, 'Df_20100103': DataFrame}
```

Each data frame is composed by the same variables: "Day","Price", "Volume" and "Sale/Purchase". I want to filter those data frames by the variable "Sale/Purchase" and keep only those observations that have "Sell". For this, I use the following command:

```
sells = {k: df[df["Sale/Purchase"]=="Sell"] for k, df in dataframes.items()}
```

My command used to work perfectly but now I gives me the following error and I do not understand why. Can someone explain which is the problem?

```
 File "<ipython-input-5-73f9fbc71571>", line 26, in <module>
sells = {k: df[df["Sale/Purchase"]=="Sell"] for k, df in dataframes.items()}
 File "<ipython-input-5-73f9fbc71571>", line 26, in <dictcomp>
sells = {k: df[df["Sale/Purchase"]=="Sell"] for k, df in dataframes.items()}
 File "/Users/angelavtc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2685, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/Users/angelavtc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2692, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/Users/angelavtc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2486, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/Users/angelavtc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/Users/angelavtc/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3065, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)) 
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
KeyError: 'Sale/Purchase'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one (or more) dataframes which dont have the column `Sale/Purchase`, that's what your error says.

To test which one(s), use:

```
wrong_dfs = [k for k, df in dataframes.items() if 'Sale/Purchase' not in df.columns]
print(wrong_dfs)
```